# Monthly & bi-monthly recurrence on same weekdays using moment-recur

Tags: date, momentjs, recurrence, moment-recur

I'm totally new to `moment.js`. I just need little help for generating recurring dates. I read the documentation and not understand the use of `every()` function. In documentation they explained the use of `every()` with only start date. But how it will work for the monthly and bi-monthly recurrence on same weekdays?

**I have the following code in which I provide it a start and end date, to find monthly & bi-monthly recurring dates.**

```
  var recurrence;
  recurrence = moment().recur({
      start: baseDt,
      end: lastDt
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this you can go with something as explained below with simple JS `Date()` object.

**1.** Find the range of dates and store them in an array.

**2.** Find the week of the first date. And the day using `getDay()`.

**3.** Now loop through all your dates and check for the condition where the week and day is same. `push()` each date in an array. This array will contains all the dates of weekday in your given week number.

I hope this pseudo algo will help you out in determine the monthly recurring dates on the same weekday.